# Make variable accessible outside conditional?

Tags: objective-c

About a year ago, when I first got into programming, I learned the hard way that variables don't escape the scope of the condition they're created in. For example:

```
-(void)someMethod {
    if (x == y) {
        NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Foo"];
        NSLog(string); // outputs "Foo" to console successfully
    }
    ...
    NSLog(string); // Doesn't work, we're out of the scope of the "if" statement.
}
```

My question is, is there any way to dynamically create variables within a conditional statement and be able to access them at other times, kind of like if I declared it in my `@interface`?

**EDIT** I guess I didn't explain it well, I meant if I wanted to use it later *in other methods*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to declare (and optionally initialize) the variable outside of the if. So something like:

```
-(void)someMethod {

    NSString *string = nil;
    if (x == y) {
        string = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Foo"];
        NSLog(string); // outputs "Foo" to console successfully
    }
    ...
    NSLog(string); 
}
```

**EDIT**

To respond to your clarification, 'string' here is a local variable, local to this method. You have other options like instance variables for example. Instance methods like this one (ones that start with '-') will have access to this instance's (this object's) instance variables.

So you could do:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {

    NSString *string; // <<-- This is an instance variable (aka "ivar")
}

- (void)someMethod;
- (void)someOtherMethod;
@end

@implementation MyClass

- (void)someMethod {

    string = @"Foo";
}

- (void)someOtherMethod {

    NSLog (string); 
   // will print "Foo" provided someMethod was called before this method
}


@end
```

Obviously there's more to this than you can get in a short answer. You can have global variables. If you're new to the language, you should read properties as a very useful tool for encapsulating instance variables (useful when you want to get the memory mgmt right). But hopefully that gets you pointed in the right direction at least.

Comment: I guess I didn't explain it well, I meant if I wanted to use it later in other methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)someMethod {
    NSString *string = nil;
    if (x == y) {
        string = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Foo"];
        NSLog(string); // outputs "Foo" to console successfully
    }
    ...
    NSLog(string); // Doesn't work, we're out of the scope of the "if" statement.
}
```

Comment: I guess I didn't explain it well, I meant if I wanted to use it later in other methods.

Answer (score 1):

Consider what you're asking. You start with:

```
-(void)someMethod
{   if (x == y)
    {   NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Foo"];
        NSLog(string); // outputs "Foo" to console successfully
    }
    ...
    NSLog(string); // Doesn't work, we're out of the scope of the "if" statement.
}
```

What would you like the second `NSLog` to do? You seem to be requesting that it either work, if the body of the `if` statement has been executed, or what? Produce a dynamic "undeclared variable" error?

Now you seem to be wanting:

```
-(void)someMethod
{   if (x == y)
    {   NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Foo"];
        NSLog(string); // outputs "Foo" to console successfully
    }
    ...
}

-(void)someOtherMethod
{
    NSLog(string); // Doesn't work, we're out of the scope of the "if" statement.
}
```

What do you wish to happen in `someOtherMethod` if the body of the `if` statement in `someMethod` has not been executed?

As @Daniel's solution points out, you can reference a variable provided it is in *scope*. In the single method case you move the point of declaration out of the `if` and into the enclosing method body. In the two method case you move it to the class - as an instance variable.

Now *scope* isn't the same as *lifetime* - a variable can exist (be alive), but no be accessible (it is out of scope); the common example is when one method calls another, the calling method's variables stay alive but are inaccessible to the called method.

In a similar way that a variable is in *scope* does not mean that it has to contain a valid *value*. That is why @Daniel puts `nil` in the variable - you know if a value has been created inside the body of the `if` by the value of `string` not being `nil`.

So maybe this is the "dynamic" behaviour you seem to be seeking - you must declare some way to reference the value (the variable), but you indicate whether it has been created by storing some sentinel (`nil` in this case) in the variable.